# OAuth 2.0 User Data

Tags: python, authentication, user-interface

Having trouble implementing OAuth 2.0 authentication in my Python web application. The authorization process seems fine, but I'm facing issues when trying to retrieve user data from the provider. Could anyone provide guidance on properly handling OAuth 2.0 user data retrieval in Python

```
import requests
from flask import Flask, redirect, request, session

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'your_secret_key'  # Change this to a secure secret key

# OAuth 2.0 configuration
CLIENT_ID = 'your_client_id'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'your_client_secret'
AUTHORIZATION_BASE_URL = 'https://provider.com/oauth2/authorize'
TOKEN_URL = 'https://provider.com/oauth2/token'
USERINFO_URL = 'https://provider.com/oauth2/userinfo'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    if 'token' in session:
        #user data retrieval
        return "Hello, User! Your data: {}".format(retrieve_incomplete_user_data())
    else:
        return "Welcome! <a href='/login'>Log in</a> with OAuth 2.0"

        #user data retrieval function
def retrieve_incomplete_user_data():
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {session["token"]["access_token"]}'}
    response = requests.get(USERINFO_URL, headers=headers)
    # Here we return a simple message instead of the complete user data
    return "Incomplete user data response: {}".format(response.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

What I've Tried:
I've verified that the authorization process works, as I'm able to get the access token successfully.
I've checked the OAuth provider's documentation to ensure that I'm using the correct user info endpoint URL.
I've confirmed that the access token is included in the request headers.
I've tested the user info endpoint using tools like cURL, and it returns the expected data.

Expectation:
I expect to receive the user's data in JSON format. However, the response I'm getting seems to be missing the expected user data fields.

Comment: Can you share provider.com token API documentation URL? I can't find it.